# how to use id in included php file

Tags: php, url, variables

I've got a page in which i include a .php file. This included file has an unique id. So If id=10, then file is 10.php, and if id=150 then file is 150.php. All those files are different. 
But inside that (let's say) 150.php file, i have some content. There may be some text and some pictures, with links. That is the problem. How to use that number of file inside that file and to call picture with the same :id".jpg?

I tried to use this line from page

```
$fajl = $aItemInfo['id'];
```

and to put inside that included "id".php

```
<img alt="bla-bla" src="include/<?php  $fajl ?>.jpg" />
```

but it didn't worked.

Comment: That's a bad idea to have the content stored in files that are accessed by id's. Database looks like a good replacement for the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You not echoing this id
    <img alt="bla-bla" src="include/<?php echo  $fajl ?>.jpg" />

Answer (score 0):

```
<img alt="bla-bla" src="include/<?=$fajl?>.jpg" />
```